# Wordpress Custom Fields Checkbox - PHP If Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Basically I have some custom fields set up which the admin can complete to show a 'deal' on the homepage. However, there will be times when a deal isn't running, so I've added a checkbox which simply says 'no_deal'.

What I am wanting to do is write an if statement in my page template which displays either the deal (if the checkbox isn't ticked), or a placeholder image (if the checkbox is ticked).

I've been on the Advanced Custom Fields website - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/ but I'm unsure what to do.Below is what I have attempted but it doesn't work and just breaks the page. Thanks!

```
<?php if( in_array( 'no_deal', the_field('no_deal') ) { ?>
                                <h4 class="box-heading">NO DEAL</h4>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <h4 class="box-heading"><?php the_field( 'deal_title' ); ?></h4>
                                <div class="deal-title"><?php the_field( 'deal_value' ); ?></div>
                                <div class="deal-subtitle"><?php the_field( 'deal_subtitle' ); ?></div>
                                <div class="deal-terms"><?php the_field( 'deal_terms' ); ?></div>
                            <?php }); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_field` instead.

From the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/):

- `get_field`: returns an array of values
- `the_field`: returns a string containing all values separated by a comma

So, you want something like this:

```
if( in_array( 'no_deal', get_field('no_deal') )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect thanks. I also had a bracket in the wrong place which was causing the page to break.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! :)